QPrintPreviewDialog genera una autonumeración por defecto
Continuando con el desarrollo de mi aplicación Notepad he intentado crear una previzualización para que se pueda imprimir el documento, pero al momento de generar la previsualización se crea una autonumeración por defecto, como hago para poder quitar esa autonumeración o hacer que aparezca a solicitud del usuario final no se que parametro controla eso o como acceder a el

Codigo:
 def prin_preview(self):
    """
    This funciton create a window that allows to the customer customize his page size
    :return: QPrinter
    """
    self.preview_page_dialog = QPrintPreviewDialog()
    self.preview_page_dialog.setWindowIcon(QIcon("Icons/Main_logo.png"))
    self.preview_page_dialog.paintRequested.connect(self.prepare_the_document_to_visualize)
    self.preview_page_dialog.exec_()


def prepare_the_document_to_visualize(self,printer: QPrinter):
    self.printer = printer
    self.printer.setDocName(f"{self.windowTitle()} - " + str(self.current_tab_info.name))
    document = self.current_plain_text_widget.document()
    document.print_(self.printer)


def print_document(self):

    self.printer = QPrinter()

    dialog_printer = QPrintDialog(self.printer)

    if dialog_printer.exec_():
        self.printer.setDocName(f"{self.windowTitle()} - " + str(self.current_tab_info.name))
        document = self.current_plain_text_widget.document()
        document.print(self.printer)


De acuerdo con esta respuesta a una pregunta similar en el foro de Qt, cito (traducción libre):

Si se consulta el código fuente de print(), se notará que
< QPointF pageNumberPos; > sólo es definido cuando no hay un
QTextDocument.pageSize() válido.
printPage() solo imprimirá el número de página si pageNumberPos no
es null.
Así que solo establece un QTextDocumtent.pageSize() válido y no
tendrás números de pagina en el documento impreso.

El código en C++ ofrecido en la propia respuesta transladado a PyQt5 sería algo así:
from PyQt5 import QtCore

...

paper_size = QtCore.QSizeF()
paper_size.setWidth(printer.width())
paper_size.setHeight(printer.height())
document.setPageSize(paper_size)
document.print_(self.printer)

En PyQt6 también podrías hacer algo como:
document.setPageSize(printer.pageRect(QPrinter.Unit.Point).size())
document.print(self.printer)


Quiero Agradecerte por la ayuda realmente funciono y no aparece la numeración

Intente hacerlo de esta manera pero al momento de escribir el texto se elimina y no me sale la previzualización, sale en blanco

Tendrás alguna solución para esto
